# VIsual Studio 2012 with TFS 2010 create workspace from template

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Having recently upgraded to VS2012 I recently had to connect to an instance of TFS2010 and cant now create a workspace mapping from a template. It used to be available via the team members node in team explorer but that has disappeared now.
Anyone know if this is still possible? Its a really useful feature

Answer (score 3):

I checked the visual studio extensions gallery Q & A for tfs power tools...

> Ewald Hofman - TFS Product Team
>
> That is correct behavior. The Team Members are redesigned in the TFS 2012 power tools and are incompatible with TFS 2010. If you want to use it for TFS 2010 you need to install VS 2010 and the 2010 power tools."

Answer (score 1):

They're part of the Team Foundation Server Power tools. You'll need to install the [2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775) (or the [2012 Update 1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)) version to get said functionality.

[image: Team Utilities in Visual Studio 2012]

But as Ewald has pointed out in the Q&A, it doesn't work when connecting to TFS2010. That only works when using Visual Studio 2010 and the 2010 Power tools. Installing the TFS2010 and 2012 powertools side by side requires some fiddling, since you want only one version of the Windows Explorer extensions and the Powershell cmd-lets installed.

---

From the [Q&A Section of the TFS 2012 Update 1 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f):

> Edward Tollenaar | Written December 19, 2012
>
> I've found some discussion about this, but it wasn't completely clear
> for me. I've installed VS2012 update 1 and the corresponding Power
> Tools.
>
> When I connect to TFS2012, I see the team members and team utilities
> (between Web Access and Settings). When I connect to TFS2010, I don't
> see this. Previous, when I used VS2010, I had access to it.
>
> Is this correct behavior? So this is only available when using VS2012
> and TFS2012 and not when using VS2012 and TFS2010?
>
> ---
>
> Ewald Hofman - TFS Product Team | Written January 09, 2013
>
> That is correct behavior. The Team Members are redesigned in the TFS
> 2012 power tools and are incompatible with TFS 2010. If you want to
> use it for TFS 2010 you need to install VS 2010 and the 2010 power
> tools.

Comment: I already have TFS 2012 power tools installed but I don't have the Team Utilities option available. it looks this feature is unavailable when connecting from VS2012 to TFS2010?